# Jquery function not being called in ASP Razor View

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am newbie to MVC world and I am trying to make an ajax call to get json data from database by calling the controller action method, everytime I run the application, data is being displayed as raw JSON data on the view rather than rendering as per my jquery code. Could you please help me guide what am I doing wrong here?

```
My Controller:

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Question")]
public ActionResult GetQuestionPost()
{
    QuestionDefViewModel quesDef = new QuestionDefViewModel();
    OnlineExamEntities db = new OnlineExamEntities();
    quesDef.questionText = db.Questions.Where(z => z.questionId == 1000).Select(z => z.questionText).SingleOrDefault();

    var query = (from p in db.Choices
                 where p.questionId == 1000
                 select new
                 {
                     choiceId = p.choiceId,
                     choiceText = p.choiceText,
                     isCorrect = p.isCorrect
                 }).ToList();

    quesDef.Choices = query.Select(x => new Choice
    {
        choiceId = x.choiceId,
        choiceText = x.choiceText,
        isCorrect = x.isCorrect
    }).ToList();
    return Json(quesDef, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My View:

```
@model ExamPortal.ViewModels.QuestionDefViewModel
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
        debugger;
        alert("hi");
        function question() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Question',
                type: 'Post',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    question = json;
                    renderQuestion(json);
                }
            });
        }

        function renderQuestion(q) {
            $('.questionText').html(q.questionText);
            for (var i = 0; i < q.Choices.length; i++) {
                $('.alternatives').append('<input id="alt' + q.Choices[i].Id + '" name="alternatives" type= radio"' + ' />' + q.Choices[i].Id + '. ' + q.Choices[i].Text + '<br />');
            }
        }
    })
</script>

<div>
    <h4>QuestionDefViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="questionText"></div>
    <div class="alternatives"></div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

I am being displayed output as below without rendering as described in the jquery function.

```
{"questionId":0,"questionText":"This is the first question","Choices":[{"choiceId":6000,"questionId":0,"choiceText":"Option A","isCorrect":"Yes       ","Exams":[],"Question":null},{"choiceId":6001,"questionId":0,"choiceText":"Option B","isCorrect":"No        ","Exams":[],"Question":null},{"choiceId":6002,"questionId":0,"choiceText":"Option C","isCorrect":"No        ","Exams":[],"Question":null},{"choiceId":6003,"questionId":0,"choiceText":"Option D","isCorrect":"No        ","Exams":[],"Question":null}]}
```

Comment: Have you shown us the correct method (you ajax calls `GetQuestion()` but that is not the method you have shown)?

Comment: Where do you even call that `question()` function?

Comment: My intention was to load the question() function on page load

Comment: @stephen Muecke sorry I updated the post. the ajax function calls question() function.

Comment: Couple of things - remove one of the script tags for jQuery. At the moment you're loading both the unminified as well as the minified version, you only need one. Secondly, you're specifying a POST request in your ajax call, but your action is only allowing a GET, so it shouldn't be working at all as far as I can see.

Comment: @Chris i removed one of the tag and changed POST to GET, still not able to render jquery functions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Action Method's verb, Ajax request type should be ***GET*** instead of ***POST***.

In addition, q.Choices[i] should be ***choiceId*** and ***choiceText***, because those are Choice entity's property names.

*For debugging, let returns static data from server first before querying from database. Otherwise, you won't know where the error is.*

[image]

### View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        debugger;
        alert("hi");

        function question() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Question',
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    question = json;
                    renderQuestion(json);
                }
            });
        }

        function renderQuestion(q) {
            $('.questionText').html(q.questionText);
            for (var i = 0; i < q.Choices.length; i++) {
                $('.alternatives').append('<input id="alt' + q.Choices[i].choiceId +
                    '" name="alternatives" type= radio" />' +
                    q.Choices[i].choiceId + '. ' + q.Choices[i].choiceText + '<br />');
            }
        }

        question();
    });
</script>

<div>
    <h4>QuestionDefViewModel</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="questionText"></div>
    <div class="alternatives"></div>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("Question")]
    public ActionResult GetQuestionPost()
    {
        QuestionDefViewModel quesDef = new QuestionDefViewModel();
        quesDef.questionText = "Sample Question";
        quesDef.Choices = new List<Choice>
        {
            new Choice { choiceId = 1, choiceText = "One", isCorrect = true},
            new Choice { choiceId = 2, choiceText = "Two", isCorrect = false},
            new Choice { choiceId = 3, choiceText = "Three", isCorrect = true},
        };
        return Json(quesDef, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

### Other Classes

```
public class Question
{
    public int questionId { get; set; }   
    public string questionText { get; set; }   
}

public class Choice
{
    public int choiceId { get; set; }
    public string choiceText { get; set; }
    public bool isCorrect { get; set; }
    public int questionId { get; set; }
}
```